# Timer does not call function using Reactive Extension

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I am new to the reactive extension implementation but while I was trying to implement a polling timer that polls a database for some query using Observable.Timer, it seems the database query function is never getting called.Please let me know why timer is not calling function at its polling time.

ServerOperationDataModel is a server object which have basic db details.

```
public void RaiseObserver(ServerOperationDataModel obj)
     {
            var pollingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            var dbQueryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            //You will want to have your Rx query timeout after the expected silence of the timer, and then further maximum silence.
            var rxQueryTimeOut = pollingPeriod + dbQueryTimeout;        
            var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts) { Name = "DatabasePoller" });        
            var query = Observable.Timer(pollingPeriod, scheduler)
                            .SelectMany(_ => GetCountFromDb(obj).ToObservable())
                            .Timeout(rxQueryTimeOut, scheduler)
                            .Retry()    //Loop on errors
                            .Repeat();  //Loop on success

            query.StartWith("DBOPerationStarte");
} 

public void GetCountFromDb(ServerOperationDataModel obj)
        {
            ServerOperationDataModel serverObject = (ServerOperationDataModel)obj;
            DataBaseHandler dbHandler = new DataBaseHandler(serverObject.DataBaseIP, serverObject.DataBasePort, serverObject.DataBaseName, serverObject.DataUserName, serverObject.DataUserPassword);   
           int attempts = 0;  
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    dbHandler.connect();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    break;
                    serverObject.DataBaseConnectionStatus = false;
                    log.Error("Connection attempt " + attempts + " failed.Retrying connection. Exception details :" + ex.ToString());
                    attempts++;
                }
            } while (attempts < _connectiontRetryAttempts && !dbHandler.isConnected());
            if (dbHandler.isConnected())
            {
                serverObject.DataBaseConnectionStatus = true;
                DataView dv = new DataView();
                dv = dbHandler.runNonTrasectionalQuery(@"with trd as (select a.userid, count(a.userid) as tradeCount from(select distinct(exorderno), userid from trades ) as a group by a.userid),ord as (select userid, count(distinct exorderno) as orderCount from orders  group by userid)select o.userid,o.orderCount,t.tradeCount from ord o inner join trd t on o.userid = t.userid");    
                if (dv != null && dv.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
                    _dt = dv.ToTable();

                    int sumoftrades = Convert.ToInt32(_dt.Compute("SUM(tradecount)", string.Empty));
                    int sumoforders = Convert.ToInt32(_dt.Compute("SUM(ordercount)", string.Empty));

                    obj.TradeCount = sumoftrades;
                    obj.OrderCount = sumoforders;
                    obj.ExtraEdge = 0;    
                }
                else
                {
                    //string msgLog = "Server : " + obj.ServerComponentIdentifier + " | " + obj.IPstring + " No result for trade/order counter/ExtraEdge";
                    //LoggerUpdate.LogMessage(msgLog, LOGTYPE.POLLINGDATABASE, LoggerUpdate.ReturnLogDisplayObject(DateTime.Now, obj.ServerComponentIdentifier + "|" + obj.IPstring, Convert.ToInt16(LOGTYPE.POLLINGDATABASE), obj, msgLog));

                    obj.TradeCount = 0;
                    obj.OrderCount = 0;
                    obj.ExtraEdge = 0;
                }  
                dbHandler.disConnect();   
            }
            else
            {
                //string msgLog = "Server : " + obj.ServerComponentIdentifier + " | " + obj.IPstring + "Connection cannot be established with the DB: " + obj.DataBaseIP + " | "+ obj.DataBasePort + " | " + obj.DataBaseName + " after a series of retries";
                //LoggerUpdate.LogMessage(msgLog, LOGTYPE.POLLINGDATABASE, LoggerUpdate.ReturnLogDisplayObject(DateTime.Now, obj.ServerComponentIdentifier + "|" + obj.IPstring, Convert.ToInt16(LOGTYPE.POLLINGDATABASE), obj, msgLog));
            }    
}
```

Comment: This code is a bit weird. You can't call `.ToObservable()` on a `void` method. You really should post your real code.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for pointing out this.I did make changes to original code already.Its basically a async function of return type bool[public  async Task<bool>GetCountFromDb(ServerOperationDataModel  obj) ].I will update my code here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there's no `Subscribe()`. All Rx queries do nothing if there's no subscribe (or something wrapping a subscribe) at the bottom.

If you change `query.StartWith("DBOPerationStarte")` to `query.StartWith("DBOPerationStarte").Subscribe()`, it will work.

This isn't very reactive code though: You may be better off using TPL for this.

Comment: thanks for clearing out this item.Now it works.Currently I have already set this off using TPL